# How to get the text from navigator.notification.prompt in ios?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am beginner in phonegap.And I googled for finding my answer about how to get the text from navigator.notification.prompt in ios.But I could not get any relevant answers.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it on the success callback, the results will have an input1 value. See full example:

```
function onPrompt(results) {
    alert("You selected button number " + results.buttonIndex + " and entered " + results.input1);
}

navigator.notification.prompt(
    'Please enter your name',  // message
    onPrompt,                  // callback to invoke
    'Registration',            // title
    ['Ok','Exit'],             // buttonLabels
    'Jane Doe'                 // defaultText
);
```